# Flutter app is giving an error 'app_name' depends on flutter any from sdk which doesn't exist (unknown sdk "flutter'"), version solving failed

Tags: dart, flutter

while running **flutter packages get** command I'm getting the below error.

Error started at the time I added the below plugin.

```
flutter_native_image:
  git: https://github.com/btastic/flutter_native_image.git
```

Even after removing the plugin I'm still getting the same error!

[image]

I'm trying to add [flutter_native_image](https://github.com/btastic/flutter_native_image) plugin

pubspec.yaml

```
    name: login_authentication
    description: A new Flutter project.

    version: 1.0.0+1

    environment:
      sdk: ">=2.0.0-dev.68.0 <3.0.0"

    dependencies:
      flutter:
        sdk: flutter'

      # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
      # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
      cupertino_icons: ^0.1.2

      firebase_auth:

      firebase_storage:

      google_sign_in:

      image_picker:

    dev_dependencies:
      flutter_test:
        sdk: flutter

    # The following section is specific to Flutter.
    flutter:
      uses-material-design: true
```

Comment: Show your pubspec

Comment: Your environment misses that flutter statement and there is a little ' written after flutter in your dependencies

Comment: gotcha! many Thanks

Comment: I think at the time of adding flutter_native_image dependency I did that mistake!  And I thought like project was broken. However many Thanks @VidorVistrom

Comment: glad to hear that :)

Answer (score 1):

Below steps resolved my issue

1. Go to **File** Menu and click on **settings**.
2. Open **Languages and Frameworks** => **Flutter**.
3. You will see a Flutter SDK path empty. Provide the location for your flutter SDK where you've downloaded your flutter from the web.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing works, until I reinstall Flutter entirely then it's working.